# Split string in the Python script

Tags: python, split

I have following string under variable test:

```
1 - 10 of 20 Results
```

I want to split this string and need 20 as a result.

I am using the following script to achieve this:

```
result=test.split('of')
mid_result=result[1].split(" ")
final_result=mid_result[1]
```

Is there any way to achieve this in one line or any direct method ?

Thanks.

Comment: Split on whitespace and take the 5th result. Assuming the string always has the same format, spacing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
result = test.split('of')[1].split(" ")[1]
```

But this would be faster:

```
result = test.split(' ')[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
result = test.split('of')[1].split(" ")[1]
```

Splitting on whitespaces seems better idea. Thanks Useless

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.split` method like this,

```
str.split(' ')[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right, but there is not need to split it first by the word "of".

```
test.split(" ")[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = test.split( )[-2]
```

Use a reverse index. much easier and more fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of that the format of string remains same for all the strings you are processing, it can be accomplished in the following ways.

```
test.split(' ')[4]
test.split(' ')[-2]
```

**explanation:**

```
test.split(' ')
```

will return u a list of

```
['1', '-', '10', 'of', '20', 'Results']
```

and the 4th element left to right and the second element right to left will give you the result.